# Weblogic log filters customization

Tags: logging, weblogic-10.x

There is an exception thrown and logged by the EJB container before I can handle it in my code (catch-block), so I decided to filter it. So, I am trying to create a weblogic log filters like explained [here](http://javaosdev.blogspot.de/2011/10/weblogic-log-filter-kung-fu.html)

Everything works fine as long as my filter looks like this:

```
NOT(MESSAGE LIKE '%java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException%')
```

But when i try to specify it more, for example which unique constraint I want to filter it is not filtering anything.

For example, I tried both:

```
NOT(MESSAGE LIKE '%ORA-00001: unique constraint (SOME.UQ_MY_CONSTRAINT violated%')
```

and

```
 NOT(MESSAGE LIKE '%java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SOME.UQ_MY_CONSTRAINT) violated%')
```

Even when I try to escape the special characters these messages continue to show in the log.

Here is the [Oracle configurational tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/wldf_configuring/appendix_query.html#wp1054866)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/wldf_configuring/appendix_query.html#1064265) it is said

> ...A backslash character (\) can be used to escape special characters, such as a quote (`) or a percent character (%)...

But they are not giving full list of the special characters (or at least I couldn't find it)

The problem here was very simple - I was not escaping the brackets - ( and ). So, the log filter should look like this:

```
NOT(MESSAGE LIKE '%java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint \(SOME.UQ_MY_CONSTRAINT\) violated%')
```